# fade in/out between two divs on a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i go about make two divs fade in/out alternating between the two, so that only one is visible at a time? And also make it in a never ending loop?

Thanks in advance!!

I know it should be done with the .fadeOut and .fadeIn - but not sure how to make it loop over and over again.

Comment: Check out [JavaScript loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). They're *so* cool.

Comment: Using [intervals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my own version a la fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3KydB/

```
window.switchIn = function () {
    $('.red').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.blue').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {window.switchOut();}, 500);
        });
    });

}

window.switchOut = function () {
    $('.blue').fadeToggle(function() {
        $('.red').fadeToggle(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {window.switchIn();}, 500);
        });
    });

}

setTimeout(function() {window.switchIn();}, 500)
```

Comment: Will this work if each div is a link, or has a link that you need to click?

Answer (score 3):

The solution for your question is a little more tricky than a simple `fadeToggle` because you don't want either DIV to display at the same time. The key is to chain the fade actions together, so the next fade action won't execute until the previous one has completed.

Logically, you want: DIV1 fade in, DIV1 fade out, DIV2 fade in, DIV2 fade out, repeat.

My solution below will take any two elements on the page and oscillate their visibility *without* showing either one at the same time. `iDuration` specifies the time for each transition in milliseconds.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sNbcH/)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">DIV #1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">DIV #2</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function runToggle(iDuration, domFirst,domSecond) {
        $(domFirst).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {
          $(domFirst).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {
            $(domSecond).fadeToggle(iDuration,"linear",function() {
              $(domSecond).fadeToggle(iDuration,"linear",function() {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      runToggle(domFirst,domSecond) ;
                  },50);
              });
            }); 
          });
       }); 
};

runToggle(1000, $('#div1'),$('#div2'));
```

I use the `setTimeout` not for timing purposes, but just to free up the JavaScript interpreter so the browser can do other things while this fade loop is running.

Answer (score 0):

How are you, you can do this.

**setInterval()** - executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals;

**setInterval(code,millisec,lang)**

So, you can create a function that make it. an Example

```
<div id="one" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){MakeToggleDivs();},1000);
});
function MakeToggleDivs(){
$('#one').fadeToggle(400);
$('#two').fadeToggle(400);
}
</script>
```

And this has to work, tell me if it doesn't.

Good luck!

Comment: The OP wants to avoid seeing both DIVs at the same time--with this solution you would briefly see both at the same time while the transition is in progress.