# setInterval not working properly with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

I've made an image fader using 2 `<div>`s (one is an image and the other is a ul containing several images)
the script is working perfectly on firefox and Safari but not working properly on Chrome, it just does the first fade and then it stops
the script is this

```
$("#second").css({
    opacity: 0.0
});

$(function () {
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 4000);
});

function rotateImages() {

    if ($("#first").css("opacity") == 1) {
        $("#first").animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 1500);
        $("#second").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        $("#second").animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 1500);
        $("#first").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1500);
    };

};
```

I don't know where exactly the problem is and how to make the script work on all browsers.
any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/JLC2q/

Comment: NITPICK: do not keep using `$("#XXXX")` over and over again, store it into a variable and use that so you are not constantly doing DOM look ups to get the element you already found once.

Comment: @user2674916 It is really hard without your interaction.  Come up and place your comments. if resolved, place the reason or share the errors.

Comment: I tried all suggestions and it's still the same, works fine with all browsers except Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fade in/out between two divs on a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589842/fade-in-out-between-two-divs-on-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AEjda/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#second").css({
    opacity: 0.0
  });
  setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);    
});
function rotateImages() {
    if ($("#first").css("opacity") == 1) {
        $("#first").animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 1500);
        $("#second").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        $("#second").animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 1500);
        $("#first").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1500);
    };

};
```

However it can be MUCH simpler.

For example [this almost works](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XfPqZ/), but 
[this one is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590297/295783)

```
$(function() {
  var $first = $("#first");
  var $second  = $("#second");
  $("#second").hide();

  var tId = setInterval(function() {
      $first.fadeToggle("slow",function() {
        $second.fadeToggle("slow");
      })    
  },4000);          
});
```

Comment: Except it needed to be wrapped in $(function() {}

Comment: Not if the code is after the element and that would NOT effect the looping from running since it is not checking for zero on the second element.

Comment: @mplungjan Do we need to assign it to a variable var `tId =` ?

Comment: I never assume the code is after the element when people complain something does not work here at SO

Comment: @mplungjan killing it using clearInterval.  I didn't realized it.  Nice one.  But without OP's interaction it is really hard to get it.

Comment: thanks a lot, what you've suggested with fadeToggle works but it's a bit jittery

Comment: @Shikiryu - it is very unlikely the user will return. 1 point since August 2012 so not active at all at SO. We can hope, he was last seen in September

Comment: @mplungjan the point is to give him a notification, so maybe (s)he'll see my message!

Answer (score -1):

Remove `()` and quotes

```
   setInterval(rotateImage, 4000);
```

Comment: However that is not the reason

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the edit.  I thought it was a syntax error.  watching closing to figure it out.

Comment: No that is wrong, http://jsfiddle.net/AEjda/5/ check this it is working.  Better make  your fiddle here and share the link

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 4000);
});
```

change to

```
setInterval(function(rotateImages()), 4000);
```

Comment: same as setInterval(rotateImages, 4000); and will alas not solve it anyway